# bootstrap css is not loading in .ejs file?

Tags: css, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

I am beginner in ejs and Nodejs.I have Nodejs file.whenever localhost hits the get request.I 'm redirecting this **index.ejs** file.I 'm getting the data in the browser.but css not loaded what's the problem in this code.I have attached the sample code...Can anyone give me the solution.Thanks in advance...

```html
index.ejs


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link ref="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>User Authentication with Passport,Express4 and MongoDB </h1>
            <h3>Login or Register with...</h3>
            <a href="/login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Login</a>
            <a href="/register" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

It's working fine...

Answer (score -3):

use rel="stylesheet" instead of ref="stylesheet"

Comment: Yes, exactly like in the existing answer from 2019... Please don't post solutions that have already been posted.

Comment: This answer is already included in the answer given above.